# Single point ordered crossover in matlab

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I need to create ordered crossover in matlab. I have parents P1 and P2 as follow:

```
P1=[1 2 3 4 ; 0 1 1 0],
P2=[3 2 1 4 ; 0 1 0 0].
```

First 1 [at place P1(2,2) and P2(2,2)] is my crossover point. now I need to offsprings as follow:

```
O1=[1 2 3 4 ; 0 1 0 0],
O2=[3 2 1 4 ; 0 1 0 0].
```

Can you please help me? Best, Elnaz

Comment: I think there is an error here, I think O2 should be [3 2 1 4; 0 1 1 0] maybe?

Comment: @user2286747 What's your crossover technique? Can you illustrate where your crossover point is?

Comment: @Dan No it is correct, O2 gives its first part from P2 (3 2 ; 0 1) and its last part from P1 (3 4 ; 1 0) the to consider permutation because 3 is in the first part so it should check which digit is not present to pick that. So it should pick (1 4; 0 0).

Comment: @EitanT it is single point order crossover and when we see the first digit 1 in second row of P1 we should set as cross point.

Comment: @user2286747 So how do you determine the crossover point? Is it predefined, or is it determined by the location of the first "1" in the second line of each parent?

Comment: @EitanT It is determined by the location of the first "1" in the second line of each parent.

Comment: @user2286747 And what was that about the permutation and the digit that is not present?

Comment: @EitanT if i want to remove one or two columns in a matrix what should i do? for example i have [1 2 3 4; 0 1 0 0]. Now i want to remove column [2;1] and [4;0]?

Comment: @user2286747 To remove the 2nd and 4th columns, you'd write `A(:, [2 4]) = 0` (if `A` is the name of the variable that stores your matrix). Did the answer I posted below help you?

Answer (score 2):

To find the crossover point, use a logical AND operator on the second line of the parents:

```
idx = find(P1(2, :) & P2(2, :));
```

Then we create the offsprings by switching values between parents after the crossover point:

```
O1 = [P1(:, 1:idx), P2(:, idx + 1:end)];
O2 = [P2(:, 1:idx), P1(:, idx + 1:end)];
```

Hope this helps!