# matlab crossover genetic algorithm

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to implement the Genetic Algorithm. I am trying to implement the single order crossover. I am unable to do so. Please help!

Suppose this is my population

```
new_pop =

0000011001
0000011001
0000000100
0000011001
0000011001
0000010001
```

I want to randomly select 2 parents from this set and do single order crossover. The set I have given above is ordered i.e., meaning the fitter individuals are placed above. How can I do the single order crossover ?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I will edit the question if it is not clear !

Comment: related question: [Single point ordered crossover in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302382/single-point-ordered-crossover-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
%Randomly choose 2 individuals

n = size(new_pop, 1);
l = size(new_pop, 2);

breeders = new_pop(randperm(n,2),:);

%Choose a crossover point

cp = randperm(l, 1);

%Crossover

b1 = [breeders(1, 1:cp), breeders(2, cp+1:end)];
b2 = [breeders(2, 1:cp), breeders(1, cp+1:end)];
```

Comment: I edited your answer! Please check it!

Comment: Hi there, could you tell me how can I select in such a way such that the probability of selecting the fitter parents are higher !

Comment: So you want to know how to pick an element from a vector where the probability of being selected is proportional to the magnitude? I suggest you try work it out and if you cant, ask that as a new question.

Comment: @roni sure, if this helped then please consider accepting it as correct?